# Secret interpolation is giving syntax error in caller workflow when calling a resusable workflow in GitHub Action

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I am using [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows) and when passing a `secrets` from caller workflow to reusable workflow, I am getting following syntax error:

```sh
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/caller_workflow.yml (Line: 28, Col: 28): Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'. Located at position 1 within expression: secrets.SECRET_1 .github/workflows/caller_workflow.yml (Line: 29, Col: 22): Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'. Located at position 1 within expression: secrets.SECRET_2
```

Not sure why the interpolation is not working.

**This is my caller workflow `caller_workflow.yml`(giving above error):**

```
name: Build workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
      - main
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - edited
      - reopened
    branches:
      - main
      - dev

jobs:
  # reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#example-caller-workflow
  org-checks:
    uses: repo/.github/workflows/main_workflow.yml@main
    with:
      SECRET_1: ${{ secrets.SECRET_1 }}
      SECRET_2: ${{ secrets.SECRET_2 }}
```

**This is my reusable workflow:**

```yaml
name: CI workflow
on:
  workflow_call:  # enables this workflow to be reusable for other repo
    secrets:
      SECRET_1:
        description: 'secret 1'
      SECRET_2:
        description: 'secret 2'
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - edited
      - reopened
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  job-name-to-run:
       ...... ......
```

secrets in other flow are working all fine with the same syntax.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was passing a secret in the wrong way. In my workflow, the secrets were passed using the `with` input parameter hence the error. `with`  will work fine while passing the input to the called (reusable) workflow but not for secrets.
For passing the secrets use `secrets` parameter.

**Here is updated `caller_workflow.yaml`** :

```
name: Build workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
      - main
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - edited
      - reopened
    branches:
      - main
      - dev

jobs:
  # reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#example-caller-workflow
  org-checks:
    uses: repo/.github/workflows/main_workflow.yml@main
    secrets:
      SECRET_1: ${{ secrets.SECRET_1 }}
      SECRET_2: ${{ secrets.SECRET_2 }}
```

(removed `with` and added `secrets`)

Reference: [Reusing workflows - example-caller-workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#example-caller-workflow)

Comment: Is this working for you? I have tried same but I am getting same compile error and it's not recognizing secrets: on caller yml file and says "Unknown key secrets"

Comment: @kinnu Yes. can you share the logs and a workflow file?

Comment: Worked for me and is indeed incorrect in the documentation. Wow, took me some time and has been sitting here for a year. I've opened an issue: https://github.com/github/docs/issues/22602

Comment: Just realized that it's not incorrect, as an action rather than a workflow is called in the example. see the above issue for my pull request.